# Soft keyboard disappears immediately when TextField is autofocused

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a TextField inside a modal bottom sheet and it has autofocus on.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class EditTask extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic currTask;
  final Function submitEdit;
  const EditTask(this.currTask, this.submitEdit, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditTask> createState() => _EditTaskState();
}

class _EditTaskState extends State<EditTask> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final myFocusNode = FocusNode();

  void initState() {
    _titleController.text = widget.currTask['desc'];
    super.initState();
  }

.
.
.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //when 'CANCEL' is pressed on DatePicker, the date is set to null, this is to prevent that
    if (_selectedDate == null) {
      _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Card(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            bottom: (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom) + 10.0,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextField(
                focusNode: myFocusNode,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                ),
                controller: _titleController,
                onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
              ),

              .
              .
              .

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget is called inside another widget via a modal bottom sheet:

```
class TaskOptions extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic currTask;
  final Function updateHasImage;
  final Function updateTaskDesc;
  const TaskOptions(this.updateTaskDesc, this.updateHasImage, this.currTask,
      {Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (bCtx) {
                  return EditTask(currTask, updateTaskDesc);
                });
          },
          child: const Text('Edit Task'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          style: currTask['hasImage']
              ? TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.red)
              : null,
          onPressed: () {
            updateHasImage();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: currTask['hasImage']
              ? const Text('Remove Image')
              : const Text('Attach Image'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The soft keyboard appears and disappears immediately when the modal bottom sheet appears and the autofocused TextField becomes unfocused. What's interesting is, **when the app is rebuilt, this error does not occur the FIRST time,** the keyboard appears and stays. After that, it just keeps disappearing. I tried adding a FocusNode that's initialized outside the build method, but it did not work. What may be causing this?

I'm testing on a Pixel 4 API level 31 emulator.

Comment: What is the purpose of pop before showModalBottomSheet call?

Comment: @user18309290 The second widget is also inside a modal bottom sheet